# Rearrange the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}$ to converge to $1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have studied the Riemann's theorem about rearrangement of conditionally convergent series. Also I have seen other rearrangements of the given series on this site that converge to different sums $\ln2,\;\frac{3}{2}\ln2 $, etc. But Iam not able to visualize the rearrangement that converges to $1$. Please help. Thank You.

Comment: rearrange $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ such that it converges to $0$. note that $\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} < 0$, but $\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5} > 0$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Will try in that direction and get back to you.

Comment: the sum of the positive terms go to infinity and the sum of the negative terms go to infinity. Now start adding the positive terms in order until you firstly surprass 1. Now add next a negative term and notice we get below 1. Then again start adding positive terms until again you firstly surprass 1. Add a negative term you go below 1 and then repeat the process.

Comment: @user1952009 Hi can you elaborate on your hint.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{n=a_k}^{a_{k+1}-1} \frac{-1}{2 n }\right)+ \left(\sum_{n=b_k}^{b_{k+1}-1} \frac{1}{2 n + 1} \right)$ and the first few terms are $\frac{-1}{2}+(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5})+(\frac{-1}{4})+(\frac{1}{7}$ $+ \frac{1}{9})+\ldots$ i.e. $a_1 = b_1 = 1, a_2 = 2,b_2 = 3,a_3 = 3,b_3 = 5,\ldots$  and the partial sum oscillates around $0$, as close as possible, in the same way clark explained

Answer (score 2):

The positive terms are $$ 1, \frac 1 3, \frac 1 5, \frac 1 7, \frac 1 9, \frac 1 {11}, \frac 1 {13}, \ldots $$ Their sum diverges to $+\infty$.  The negative terms are $-1$ multiplied by $$ \frac 1 2, \frac 1 4, \frac 1 6, \frac 1 8, \frac 1 {10}, \frac 1 {12}, \ldots $$ Their sum diverges to $-\infty$.

$1 + \dfrac 1 3$ exceeds $1$.  Now add enough negative terms to that to get a sum less than $1$:
$$
1 + \frac 1 3 - \frac 1 2 = \frac 5 6 < 1.
$$
Then add enough positive terms after that to make the sum more than $1$:
$$
1 + \frac 1 3 - \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 5 = \frac{31}{30} >1.
$$
Then add enough negative terms after that to make the sum less than $1$:
$$
1 + \frac 13 - \frac12 + \frac 1 5 - \frac 1 4 = \frac{47}{60} <1.
$$
Then add enough positive terms after that to make the sum more than $1$:
$$
1 + \frac 13 - \frac12 + \frac 1 5 - \frac 1 4 \underbrace{{} + \frac 1 7 + \frac 1 9} = \frac{1307}{1260} > 1.
$$
This last time we needed two terms.  Is there a pattern to the number of terms we have to add at each step? Maybe not.  But we know that it will always be possible to make the sum more than $1$ or less than $1$ as the case may be, because the series of positive terms and the series of negative terms both diverge to infinity.

Comment: is it a hint ? you didn't prove it converges to $1$

Comment: @user1952009 : To prove it converges to $1$, notice that when you add $\pm1/n$, thereby making it go from more than $1$ to less than $1$ or vice-versa, then the difference between the sum that you get and $1$ is less than $1/n$, and that goes to $0$ as you proceed. This still omits a few details, but those are easy if onerous to fill in. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

We can do it like this.  Following each even term, add either one or two odd terms.  For $M=0,1,2,3,\dots$ we want at stage $M$ a total of $M$ even terms and $\lfloor M e^2/4 \rfloor$ odd terms.  Since $1 < e^2/4 < 2$, when $M$ increases by $1$, the value $\lfloor M e^2/4 \rfloor$ increases by either $1$ or $2$.

This arrangement of the series has sum $1$.

Explanation.
For odd terms, as $N \to \infty$ we have partial sums
$$
A_N := \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{2n+1} = \log(2\sqrt{N}\,) + \frac{\gamma}{2}+O(N^{-1})\qquad\text{as }N \to \infty
\tag1$$
($\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.)
For even terms, as $M \to \infty$ we have partial sums
$$
B_M := \sum_{n=1}^M\frac{-1}{2n} = -\log(\sqrt{M}\,) - \frac{\gamma}{2} + O(N^{-1})
\tag2$$
Now, using the scheme described above, at stage $M$, the partial sum of our rearranged series is
$B_M + A_N$ where $N = \lfloor M e^2/4 \rfloor$.  So
$$
B_M+A_N = \log\frac{2\sqrt{N}}{\sqrt{M}} + O(M^{-1})
\tag3$$
Note that
$$
\frac{Me^2}{4}-1 < N \le \frac{Me^2}{4}
\\
e^2 - \frac{4}{M} < \frac{4 N}{M} \le e^2
$$
As $M \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{4N}{M} \to e^2
\\
\frac{2\sqrt{N}}{\sqrt{M}} \to e
\\
\log\frac{2\sqrt{N}}{\sqrt{M}} \to 1
\\
B_M + A_N \to 1 .
$$