# Rearrangement of infinite series $\sum\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ to get it to converge to +infinity (diverge)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Rearrangement of elements of infinite series $\sum\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ to get it to converge to $+\infty$ (diverge)?

I found rearrangements that converge the series to $0, 1$ or $-\infty$. But I can't find a a rearrangement that converges to $+\infty$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "rearrangement"?

Comment: @Cloudy7 Here's an example of convergence to 1: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840623/rearrange-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-1n1-frac1n-to-converge-to

Comment: @amWhy I am actually a new user and this is the first question I ask. I used the website many times to find answers and not ask questions. I learned how to write the sum in that format by learning from previous google results attempted to find an answer to my question.
Here's an example of convergence to 1: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840623/rearrange-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-1n1-frac1n-to-converge-to
I also found to 0 and -infinity. However, I'm looking for divergence to +infinity.

Comment: Well, I've edited the post a bit.  + infinity is simply `$+\infty$` = $+\infty$.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks! Do you have an answer to my post tho?

Comment: It is possible that there is no such...

Comment: Why don't you try to used the same strategy used in the other posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can imitate the others answers by formalizing the following:
$$1+\frac{1}{3}>1 $$
Then you add $-1/2$ and you get
$$1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{2} $$
Now you used enough positive terms such that the sum became $>2$ and then you substract $1/4$ and so on.

The idea is just to subtract the least number of times possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $k=0$.
2. Increment $k$ by 1.
3. Add the largest positive elements that are left until the sum exceeds $k$.
4. Add the smallest negative element that is left.
5. Goto 2.

Step 4 is to make sure all negative elements are consumed.

Step 3 is always possible because the Harmonic series diverges.

Step 2 and the fact that the remaining elements converge to zero (used in step 4) accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[\left(\sum_{j=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{2j-1}\right)-\frac{1}{2k}\right] = +\infty
$$
The first few terms:
$$
\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{2}\\
+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{15} - \frac{1}{4}\\
+\frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{19}+\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{23}+\frac{1}{25}
+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{29}-\frac{1}{6}
$$

Comment: The first element is $ \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{1}\  $ which is 1 and not -1...

Comment: OK, I did $\sum (-1)^n/n$, the negative of the requested sum.  I will fix it.